# Cytoscape and selectors

Tags: python, cytoscape.js, ipycytoscape

I am not familiar with cytoscape or Java, so I do not know if there is a way to define a node size which depend on node's degree.
Currently I am using the following:

```
cytoscapeobj.set_style(
    [
        {
             'selector':node,
             'style': {
                 'font-family': 'helvetica',
                 'font-size': '20px',
                 'label': 'data(id)'
             }
        },
        {
             'selector': 'edge',
             'style': {
                 'font-family': 'helvetica',
                 'font-size': '20px',
                  'width' : 'mapData(weight)' # it is actually not working

             }
        },
        {
             'selector': 'node[Degree>0]',
             'style': {
                 'width': '100px',
                 'height': '100px'
             }
        },
    {
         'selector': 'node[Degree>1]',
         'style': {
             'width': '150px',
             'height': '150px'
         }
    },
    {
         'selector': 'node[Degree>2]',
         'style': {
             'width': '200px',
             'height': '200px'
         }
    }
]
```

)

I have thousands of nodes, some of them has degree 1 (most of them), then I have nodes with degree `2, 3, 4, 5 ,... 100, ...`
It would be not easy to add a selector for each of them.
Do you know if there is an easier way to plot any node's degree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define any required parameters in the node's [data](https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.data) and then use [style mappers](https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/mappers) to apply that data to style properties like `width` or any other. So your code is actually the right way to do that.

It doesn't work because `mapData()` and `data()` works in a different ways. While `data()` will just apply the `data` value to that property, as it does to `label` in your example, the `mapData()` requires additional parameters to be set.

Check this out:

```
width: mapData(weight, 0, 100, 1, 3)
```

In that case, `mapData` will take the value of `data.weight` and then check where is that value between 0 and 100 and proportionally set `width` to the according value between 1 and 3.

In my experience, I find it more convenient to use values, precalculated in the code. So I'd go with creating the `data.width` param and setting to the desired width and then just map the simple `data()` mapper to that value.

Comment: Hi igordata, thank you for your answer. Maybe I am just a bit confused, but I have not fully understood how to change the node's size based on the degree iteratively. could you please provide me with an example? Many thanks

Comment: I think in case of `degree` you should change this code `'selector': 'node[Degree>0]',`
to that `'selector': 'node[[degree>0]]',`